# Stuck on JOptionPane for class project

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm going a little bit ahead of my programming class and I've caught myself on a snag that I cannot figure out and I have tried everything. Basically we have to make a vending machine that only accepts dollar bills and then gives the user their change. I've commented the part that I cannot figure out how to do. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class ChangeMaker
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{

char a = "Water";
char b = "Juice";
char c = "Candy Bar";
char d = "Enery Bar";


    String machineString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Jonathan's Vending Machine\n" + "Choose a selection below\n" + "(1) Water ~ $0.35\n" + "(2) Juice ~ $0.50\n" + "(3) Candy Bar ~ $0.75\n" + "(4) Energy Bar ~ $0.95\n");

    int quarters;
    int nickels;
    int dimes;
    int pennies;
    char selection = Character.parseChar(machineString); //Determine selection
    int amount = 0;

    if (selection == 1) 
    {
        amount = 25;
    } else if (selection == 2) 
    {
        amount = 50;
    } else if (selection == 3)
    {
        amount = 75;
    } else if (selection == 4)
    {
        amount = 95;
    }


    quarters = amount / 25;
    amount = amount % 25;
    dimes = amount / 10;
    amount = amount % 10;
    nickels = amount / 5;
    amount = amount % 5;
    pennies = amount;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "You selected " + selection + " your change is:\n" + quarters + " quarters\n" + dimes + " dimes\n" + nickels + " nickels and\n" + pennies + " pennies\n" + "Enjoy yout treat!");
    System.exit(0);



}
}
```

**Working Code**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class ChangeMaker
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{


    int amount = 0;


    String machineString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Jonathan's Vending Machine\n" + "Choose a selection below\n" + "(A) Water ~ $0.35\n" + "(B) Juice ~ $0.50\n" + "(C) Candy Bar ~ $0.75\n" + "(D) Energy Bar ~ $0.95\n");


    String selection = "null";
    int quarters;
    int nickels;
    int dimes;
    int pennies;


    if (machineString.equals("a")) 
    {
        amount = 75;
        selection = "Water";
    } else if (machineString.equals("b")) 
    {
        amount = 50;
        selection = "Juice";
    } else if (machineString.equals("c"))
    {
        amount = 25;
        selection = "Candy Bar";
    } else if (machineString.equals("d"))
    {
        amount = 5;
        selection = "Energy Bar";
    }


    quarters = amount / 25;
    amount = amount % 25;
    dimes = amount / 10;
    amount = amount % 10;
    nickels = amount / 5;
    amount = amount % 5;
    pennies = amount;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "You selected " + selection + " your change is:\n" + quarters + " quarters\n" + dimes + " dimes\n" + nickels + " nickels and\n" + pennies + " pennies\n" + "Enjoy yout treat!");
    System.exit(0);



}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oracle API pages are usually really good sources for these questions. Here is one that should help here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

You cannot parse a string that is longer than 1 character into a character.

To help you point you in the right direction, try debugging what's happening with your 'machineString' variable. Add a System.out.println to a console, then you can see how you're comparing what the user is selecting versus your if statements.

Comment: I figured it out. I tweaked the code and got everything working the right way.  I edited the original post with the working code in case you're interested

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

String a = "Water";
String b = "Juice";
String c = "Candy Bar";
String d = "Enery Bar";

int quarters;
int nickels;
int dimes;
int pennies;
int selection = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Jonathan's Vending Machine\n" + "Choose a selection below\n" + "(1) Water ~ $0.35\n" + "(2) Juice ~ $0.50\n" + "(3) Candy Bar ~ $0.75\n" + "(4) Energy Bar ~ $0.95\n"));
int amount = 0;

if (selection == 1) 
    amount = 25;
 else if (selection == 2) 
    amount = 50;
 else if (selection == 3) 
    amount = 75;
 else if (selection == 4) {
    amount = 95;

quarters = amount / 25;
amount = amount % 25;
dimes = amount / 10;
amount = amount % 10;
nickels = amount / 5;
amount = amount % 5;
pennies = amount;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You selected " + selection + " your change is:\n" + quarters + " quarters\n" + dimes + " dimes\n" + nickels + " nickels and\n" + pennies + " pennies\n" + "Enjoy yout treat!");

}
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error on the line 

char selection = Character.parseChar(machineString); //Determine selection

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are declaring a String as a char.

Change:

```
char a = "Water";
char b = "Juice";
char c = "Candy Bar";
char d = "Enery Bar";
```

To:

```
String a = "Water";
String b = "Juice"
String c = "Candy Bar";
String d = "Enery Bar";
```

Since your if statement where check the decision is using integer, you should use a integer variable instead of a character. Then use the `Integer.parseInt(machineString)`

Here is the entire code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a = "Water";
    String b = "Juice";
    String c = "Candy Bar";
    String d = "Enery Bar";


    String machineString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Jonathan's Vending Machine\n" + "Choose a selection below\n" + "(1) Water ~ $0.35\n" + "(2) Juice ~ $0.50\n" + "(3) Candy Bar ~ $0.75\n" + "(4) Energy Bar ~ $0.95\n");

    int quarters;
    int nickels;
    int dimes;
    int pennies;
    int selection = Integer.parseInt(machineString);
    int amount = 0;

    if (selection == 1) {
        amount = 25;
    } else if (selection == 2) {
        amount = 50;
    } else if (selection == 3) {
        amount = 75;
    } else if (selection == 4) {
        amount = 95;
    }


    quarters = amount / 25;
    amount = amount % 25;
    dimes = amount / 10;
    amount = amount % 10;
    nickels = amount / 5;
    amount = amount % 5;
    pennies = amount;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You selected " + selection + " your change is:\n" + quarters + " quarters\n" + dimes + " dimes\n" + nickels + " nickels and\n" + pennies + " pennies\n" + "Enjoy yout treat!");
    System.exit(0);
    }
```